# HTML fields are shown empty when they contain value

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

I have an edit user form. When a user visits this page, details regarding to him are shown in the fields. He can edit the fields if he want to, and then submit the form.

```
<form id="edit-form"method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ; ?>">
<input id="txtalias" name="txtalias" type="text" value="<?php echo 1; ?>" >    
<input type="text" id="txthour_max"  name="txthour_max"  value="<?php echo 2; ?>" >chk1
<input type="text" id="txtminute_max" name="txtminute_max" value="<?php echo 3; ?>" >chk2
<input type="text" id="txthour_def" name="txthour_def" value="<?php echo 4; ?>" >chk3
<input type="text" id="txtminute_def" name="txtminute_def" value="<?php echo 5; ?>">chk4
 <button id="serv_butn" type="submit">Save settings</button>
</form>
```

This is the PHP part:

```
if((isset($_POST['txtalias']))&&(isset($_POST['txthour_max']))&&(isset($_POST['txtminute_max']))&&(isset($_POST['txthour_def']))&&(isset($_POST['txtminute_def'])))
{
    $z = $_POST['txtalias']; 
    $y= $_POST['txthour_max']; 
    $w=$_POST['txtminute_max'];  
    $x = $_POST['txthour_def']; 
    $u = $_POST['txtminute_def']; 

}
```

And if the user, doesn't want to make any changes & he clicks the submit button,

```
Notice: Undefined variable
```

is shown, even though the text fields have values stored in them.

How to solve this issue?

```
<input id="txtalias" name="txtalias" type="text" value="<?php echo $env; ?>" >
```

If this is a textbox, and when i click submit button, following notice is shown

```
Notice: Undefined variable: env in C:\wamp\www\project\mypage.php on line 212 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0010163472{main}( )..\mypage.php:0 ">
```

Comment: I don't exactly know what your problem is but it works for me. you will have to leave number 2 empty. because thats the way it needs to be according to your if. So leaving the 2nd field empty and clicking submit works.

Comment: Whats your PHP version?

Comment: @Déjà vu Think of an HTML form that has values stored in them. And even if you don't want to make any changes, you can submit that form. So when you submit the form, without any changes, Undefined variable notice is shown. How to resolve that is my question??

Comment: I don't have that problem. I pasted your php and your html in a new file. I opened it, changed all values to some random letters. Then clicked submit. This works. Then when i click submit again (with the standard 1-5 in them. It changes them all back to 1-5. So i don't really know what the problem is.

Comment: Now look at the question. i've updated it. @Déjà vu

Comment: and $env is a checkbox value?

Comment: Let $env be a value from a database table. @ Déjà vu

Comment: Well, i hope you already made a databse connection and all. And know how to setup a basic query? (if you didn't already do it). And if $env is a checkbox it works for me by the way. As you said in your example: "If this is a checkbox, and when i click submit button, following notice is shown"

Comment: I too have tried this code and is perfectly working, without any issue. May be he is trying to fool us as his name itself is joker. :P

If yes, your are going to get down voted. I will wait for some time to know if this problem is real. If not, will down vote it.

Comment: This problem is as real as you are. I am a man of my words. This is real. @AeJey

Comment: I see you changed it to textbox instead of checkbox. Still it works just fine when i use $env = $_POST['text']; and then echo $env; it will show me whatever is in the textbox

Comment: BTW: make sure you have declared your $env before you create the form!

Comment: Don't  know what is wrong. I just can't figure it out. Thanks anyway. Let me try it from the scratch. @Déjà vu

Comment: The code you copied here works perfectly. Add a `$env = 1` at the beginning of your php file, and you'll see that the problem is that you haven't declared that variable in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your

```
<input id="txtalias" name="txtalias" type="text" value="<?php echo $env; ?>">
```

$env has not define;

please check when you declare $env

Comment: Now look at the question. i've updated it. @Bipul Khan

Comment: are you trying to store a checkbox data to the $env?

Comment: It's a textbox. My mistake while typing. @ BlackJack